# Typescript type safety in conditional union type switch typing

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, union-types

I have a simple function taking a union type and a `boolean` as parameters and cannot manage to have it be typed by Typescript.

I have this code ([playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20A%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'A'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20g(a%3A%20A)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'A'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f1(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20boolean)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'A'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'A'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f2(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20boolean)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20g(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20g(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f3(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20boolean)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20g(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'A'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f4(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20boolean)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(b)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(a)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'a'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'A'%3A%20return%20''%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20g(a)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)):

```
type A = 'a' | 'A';

function f(a: A, b: boolean): string {
    if (b) {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A': return '';
        }
    } else {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A': return '';
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler (when `strictNullChecks` is enabled) tells me `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`

I really don't want to add `default` cases since the goal here is to ensure that when I add new types in `A` I handle them correctly in `f`. And I don't see which branch I am missing.

I could fix it by writing (see the linked playground):

```
function g(a: A): string {
    switch (a) {
        case 'a': return '';
        case 'A': return '';
    }
}

function f2(a: A, b: boolean): string {
    if (b) {
        return g(a);
    } else {
        return g(a);
    }
}
```

(Of course in real life I need two different g functions but for the typing issue this is not important).

How can I let typescript compile `f` without introducing intermediate functions like `g` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `default` case to fix it e.g.

```
function f(a: A, b: boolean): string {
    if (b) {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A':
            default: return '';
        }
    } else {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A':
            default: return '';
        }
    }
}
```

You also fix it by using the `never` type by returning it e.g.

```
function f(a: A, b: boolean): string {
    if (b) {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A': return '';
            default:
                const _exhaustiveCheck: never = a;
                return _exhaustiveCheck;
        }
    } else {
        switch (a) {
            case 'a': return '';
            case 'A': return '';
            default:
                const _exhaustiveCheck: never = a;
                return _exhaustiveCheck;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution with 'never' is really what I want since it compiles here and fails if I add a new type in A which was the point. Your first solution is dangerous since it don't really typecheck A (the day I add a new type in A it will apply the default behavior although I surely want to handle it differently here).

Comment: @jolivier Yes, but `never` is not available in earlier versions.